# Interpolation of data points

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation, grids-graticules, inverse-distance-weighted

I have a layer of points that represent bus stops. Each point has a value (quality of service, between `0` and `100`). I need to create a grid (resolution `25m`) by interpolating the points values.

For each cell of the grid, I want to assign the value of the best surrounding stop (search radius of `500m`), but the values of the stops should decrease linearly with the distance between them and the grid cell (`-10%` every `100m`).

For example, a grid cell located `100m` away from a stop with value `30` and `200m` away from another stop with value `80` should have the value `64` (`80 - 0.2*80`). The bus stop with the bad value `30` has no impact on this cell.

I tried IDW interpolation but I'm not getting the result I expect. I'm using QGIS.

Comment: In order to make it more complicated: How do you account for natural or artificial barriers, e.g. highways, or rivers?

Comment: Actually I don't ;)

Comment: If you don't, then both scientific and practical value of your map are at least to be doubted.

Comment: May be a possibility, but i don't have try, and not a lot elegant.. : 
1. Create a grid (point with a distance of 25 m) 
2. Calculate a distance matrix (N*kx3) betwen bus points and grid. 
3. Join quality of service in the distance matrix. 
4. Calculate a new field with something like  CASE WHEN "Distance"<500 then "bus_stops_quality" -("Distance" * "bus_stops_quality" /1000) ELSE 0 END. 
4.Join atttributes by location, select max values.

Comment: Thank you Christophe, your solution is very interesting and suits my needs. I'm currently testing it. Could you develop how to select only the max values for each grid point ? Is it something you do during the attributes joining by location or an other step that you do after?

Comment: Try the `join attributes by location (summary)` tool. It allows you to choose maximum values.

Comment: @Romain Yes, i think to the processing "join attributes by location (summary)" Ctrl+Alt+T as said csk. I don't have try, i think it works, but if you have a lot of bus stop, may be it will take time to calculate.

Comment: How did you specify your search radius? Normally IDW uses the 12 nearest neighbors to calculate the unknown location. This could result in a different map than expected,

Comment: When using IDW I used a search radius of 500 meters (because I consider that this is the maximum distance for a stop to be considered relevant at a specific location). I also changed the parameter for the maximum number of nearest neighbors to 1 (because I want only the best one around), but the algorithm took the closest one and not the best one. That said, Christophe solution seems to work quite well. I'm still testing it, I will update this post as soon as I have the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested on the solution, I tried what Christophe suggested, but with a minor modification. To summarize:

1. Create a grid and calculate a distance matrix between bus stops and grid points (only the closest 500 for each stop)
2. Join quality of service in the distance matrix and calculate a new field that accounts for the distance between stop and grid point
3. **Export to CSV and use Python to eliminate duplicates and keep only the max value for each grid point**
4. Load the new CSV in QGIS, join with grid layer and display the results!

The reason I did step 3 this way is that the attribute joining by location was far too slow to process with QGIS.

[image: Spatial interpolation of bus quality of service]